# Acuracy Level of md5sum Comparison

Tags: find, hashsum, file-comparison

Doing here some file listing with `find` command as follows:

`find /dir1/ -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort -k 2 > dir1.txt`

Then:

`find /dir2/ -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort -k 2 > dir2.txt`

Noticed that were some equal hashes despite being different files, for example, an `xxxxxxxx.jpg` image file with same hash of an `yyyyyyyy.mp3` sound file.

Main question is, which is the confiability level os a `md5sum` file comparison?

Comment: It is possible but extremely unlikely, that two different files produce the same m5sum. If you want a higher level, you can use sha256sum; it is still possible but much more unlikely, that two different files produce the same sha256sum.

Comment: It is most likely that both files have the same content even though they have different filenames with different extensions. Try `sha512sum` and if you get the same hash, the files have definitely the same content.

Comment: The md5sum appears to be 128 bits, so the chances of a random match are (to a close approximation) zero. However, there are cases where checksums are likely to be identical: for example, zero-length files, or an inadvertent rename of an identical file.

Comment: Hence we are going to try it out with `sha512sum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collision probability of md5sum is 1 in 2<sup>64</sup>. Refer [this post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12679) on crypto.se for more details.

---

**SideNote:** The contents of the file is hashed, filename doesn't play any role in hashing. Are you sure the files are differnent and not just the names?

```
$ md5 /tmp/files.txt*
MD5 (/tmp/files.txt) = 29fbedcb8a908b34ebfa7e48394999d2
MD5 (/tmp/files.txt.clone) = 29fbedcb8a908b34ebfa7e48394999d2
```